# UEA Image Labeling Tool annotation format import to Roboflow

Tags: roboflow

I'm wondering what type of format [this tool](https://github.com/yuyu2172/image-labelling-tool) (fork of a project that became the [django-labeller](https://bitbucket.org/ueacomputervision/image-labelling-tool/src/master/)) outputs, and if this json format is supported for uploading datasets to Roboflow.

An example label file (*0001__labels.json*) is:

```
{
   "image_filename": "0001.jpg",
   "complete": null,
   "labels": [
      {
         "object_id": 1,
         "label_type": "box",
         "size": {
            "y": 62,
            "x": 235
         },
         "label_class": "dog",
         "centre": {
            "y": 42.5625,
            "x": 356.5
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Is the an easy tool to convert a set of labels in this format to a format that Roboflow can ingest?

Answer (score 0):

According to the tools ReadMe that you linked to, it outputs raw JSON, which is not accepted. To upload to Roboflow annotations need to be in a supported format.  Roboflow accepts 30+ annotation formats which can be found here: https://roboflow.com/formats